# How to perform sort in js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sorting, mean

I have an array like this

```
var temp = [{"rank":3,"name":"Xan"},{"rank":1,"name":"Man"},{"rank":2,"name":"Han"}]
```

I am trying to sort it as follows

```
 temp.sort(function(a){ a.rank})
```

But its n ot working.Can anyone suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: at least, you need to return some value.

Answer (score 6):

With [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you need to check the second item as well, for a symetrical value and return a value.

```js
var temp = [{ rank: 3, name: "Xan" }, { rank: 1, name: "Man" }, { rank: 2, name: "Han" }];

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.rank - b.rank;
});

console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hehe Nina, sort questions is your favorite type, eh?

Comment: @lin, more something with array, i think.

Comment: Yes She already answered a couple like this for me before....Thanks Nina:)

Answer (score 2):

You must compare them inside the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. If the function returns a negative value, a goes before b (in ascending order), if it's positive, b goes before a. If the return value is 0, they are equal:

```
temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.rank < b.rank) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.rank > b.rank) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

You can use a shortcut method that subtracts the numbers to get the same result:

```
temp.sort((a, b) {
    return a.rank - b.rank;
});
```

For descending order:

```
temp.sort((a, b) {
    return b.rank - a.rank;
});
```

ES6 shortcut:

```
temp.sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 temp.sort(function(a, b) {return a.rank - b.rank});
```